# In Node.js, How can I access exported module in Index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have searched in stackoverflow and it seems there isn't any use case like mine.
I have a structure folders like this in functions directory:

> functions/index.js

I added some codes to be used by other functions like this in index.js:

```
require("dotenv");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const config = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
admin.initializeApp(config);

const highLevel = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: "2GB",
};

const secretLevel = {
  timeoutSeconds: 120,
  memory: "1GB",
  secret: [process.env.SERVER_BACKEND],
};

const lowLevel = {
  timeoutSeconds: 120,
  memory: "512MB",
};

module.exports = lowLevel, highLevel, secretLevel;
```

I created a file in a folder structure like this:

> functions/admin/features/music/publisher.js

How can I access the variable of **lowLevel** from publisher.js as I tried using this:

```
const lowLevel = require("../index");
```

and I can't get any of reference to index.js. Is there a way to access file index.js from the root folder? Thank you very much for any tips and trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this file:

```
 functions/admin/features/music/publisher.js
```

If you want access to this file:

```
 functions/index.js
```

You would do that with:

```
 const lowLevel = require("../../../index.js");
```

The first `..` moves up to the `functions/admin/features` directory.

The second `..` moves up to the `functions/admin` directory.

The third `..` moves up to the `functions` directory where you say that `index.js` is.

Comment: Wow, it really works. Thanks dude.